# XA+B=X will have a unique solution...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am currently stuck on this question:

Let A and B be n x n matrices. Show that if none of the eigenvalues of A are equal to 1, then the matrix equation XA+B=X will have a unique solution.

I've heard that if the eigenvalues of a matrix are not equal to 1, then it implies a unique solution. However, I'm confused how to take this one step further and prove that XA+B=X will have a unique solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ iff $A-I$ is invertible, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix of the appropriate dimension. If one of these equivalent conditions is true, we have
$$
XA+B=X\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad X(A-I)=-B \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad X = -B(A-I)^{-1}.
$$
Thus, $X$ is uniquely determined.